# How do I export a vector file for CAD?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, export

I am new to AI. I have saved my file in DWG, but the person I am sending it to says it opens in raster and has a double line. I am creating patent drawings, so there should be only one line. I am sending the file to someone who uses old-school CAD, like 1999 CAD.

Comment: EPS or DXF might work, but you really have to ask the recipient what they can handle, or at least which software and version they use.

Comment: Remember to remove any stroke you have applied, they will sometimes be interpreted as separate paths in AutoCAD. I think that's where the "two lines" are coming from.

Comment: Well i have done it from CAD to illustrator and a regular PDF worked just fine :)

Comment: Just porn the DWG into illustrator. illustrator open DWG natively

Answer (score 2):

From the Illustrator Export menu under File -> Export choose "AutoCAD Interchange File (*.DXF)"

After clicking export in the file dialog that opens, you can choose the version of cad to export for. Since you mentioned the person handling the file might be using old software you should most likely choose **R14/LT98/LT97**